# Setting wallpaper instantly with setbitmap() android

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-wallpaper, tasker

I have been searching for an answer to my problem, but cant seem to find a right answer.

I am trying to use tasker to set a background on my phone everytime a song changes. I got everything working, but setbitmap does not set wallpaper instantly. I have to interact with the phone in some way to get it to update ( open a folder, touch the screen etc). Is there a way to force an update after setbitmap has been called?

Edit: Im using setStream now. Here is a short video showing what im trying to explain in detail.

[Wallpaper delay](http://sendvid.com/5lkkt4f7)

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is your permission in place ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Alternatively you can use `setStream` instead of `setBitmap` as it takes time to *decode* a bitmap and it is directly proportional to the size of the bitmap.

Comment: Im new here and commented in the wrong place! Thank you for your answer! Yes, everthing is working. Its just that the wallpaper isnt updated instanly after setbitmap is called. It seems something must happen like userinteraction for the wallpaper to update.

Comment: You can use `AccessibilityService` to simulate user interaction.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but with the same outcome. It works, but only updates the bg when i move the screen or interact with the phone in some way.