# set wallpaper refresh on Android

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am trying to change the current user wallpaper.
I have set the set_wallpaper permission and it works.
But when I change the wallpaper I have to wait about 15 seconds to see the wallpaper change.

This is currious because if I check the lock screen it has already changed.

Here is my code:

```
 public static void setWallpaper(final Context context, final Bitmap image){
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    if(image != null){
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(image);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {}
            }
        };

        thread.start();
}
```

I'm on Android 6.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this method "refreshWallpaper(Context)" ?

Comment: It was a test, to force the wallpaper to refresh, I read that on a forum. But do not take care of it. I have tried with and without that method and the result is  the same.

Comment: See this, you already has a Refresh function, but maybe it can make work better https://stackoverflow.com/a/22932875/3117650

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try it and tell you if it works. But it looks very similar to my function (refreshWallpaper) : https://github.com/jess-bart/PictoThemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jessy_barthelemy/pictothemo/Helpers/ApplicationHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

Why you used a Thread for this purpose?

Remove that and use your code directly on MainThread and see your code works correctly and instantly changed user wallpaper!

Comment: It does not change anything. I have the same delay.

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth having a deeper look at the WallpaperManagers `setBitmap` method and the inner callback (ln 1055, ln 1713) [ref](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/app/WallpaperManager.java)

I am not entirely sure how this whole code works nor do I think this really helps you solving the problem but it might give you a hint.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270919/setting-wallpaper-instantly-with-setbitmap-android) for a similar problem

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the similar question is still unanswered.